# How to test a wheel against multiple versions of python?

Tags: python, python-packaging, tox

#### Problem description

I'm writing a python library and I am planning to upload both sdist (.tar.gz) and wheel to PyPI. The [build docs say](https://build.pypa.io/) that running

```
python -m build
```

I get sdist created from the source tree and *wheel created from the sdist*, which is nice since I get the sdist tested here "for free". Now I want to run tests (pytest) against the wheel with multiple python versions. What is the easiest way to do that?

I have been using tox and I see there's an option for [setting package to "wheel"](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#package):

```
[testenv]
description = run the tests with pytest
package = wheel
wheel_build_env = .pkg
```

But that does not say *how* the wheel is produced; I am unsure if it

a) creates wheel directly from source tree
b) creates wheel from sdist which is created from source tree in a way which *is identical to* `python -m build`
c) creates wheel from sdist which is created from source tree in a way which *differs from*  `python -m build`

*Even if the answer would be c), the wheel tested by tox would not be the same wheel that would be uploaded, so it is not testing the correct thing. **Most likely I should somehow give the wheel as an argument to tox /  test runner.***

### Question

I want to create a wheel from sdist which is created from the source tree, and I want to run unit tests against the wheel(s) with multiple python versions. This is a pure python project, so there will be only a single wheel per version of the package. What would be the idiomatic way to run the tests against the *same* wheel(s) which I would upload to PyPI? Can I use tox for that?

Comment: Typically I would use a nox/tox setup that doesn't expose the package to the python path by placing it under a "src/" dir in the repo. If you're concerned about install types, when creating a virtual environment for tests, do not perform an editable install (i.e. do not use `pip install -e .`, just `pip install .`). Then under this virtual environment you execute your tests. Tox/nox will allow you to easily specify running this setup under multiple python interpreters. Here's a toy project you can take a look at if you want some inspiration https://github.com/cal-pratt/flexdi/tree/main

Comment: When you explicitly want to use pyproject-build the you can follow these instructions https://github.com/tox-dev/tox-external-wheels#migration-guide

Comment: @JürgenGmach that looks like a perfect match! Would you want to write a full answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tox 4.12.2 documentation on [External Package builder](https://tox.wiki/en/4.14.2/config.html#external-package-builder) tells that it is possible to define an `external` package option (thanks for the comment @JürgenGmach). The external [package](https://tox.wiki/en/4.14.2/config.html#package) option means that you set

```ini
[testenv]
...
package = external
```

In addition to this, one must create a section called `[.pkg_external]`   (or `<package_env>_external` if you have edited your [package_env](https://tox.wiki/en/4.14.2/config.html#package_env) which has an alias `isolated_build_env`). In this section, one should define *at least* the [`package_glob`](https://tox.wiki/en/4.14.2/config.html#package_glob), which tells the tox where to install the wheel. If you also want to *create* the wheel, the you can do that in the `commands` option of the `[.pkg_external]`.

### Simple approach (multiple builds)

Example of a working configuration (tox 4.12.2):

```ini
[testenv:.pkg_external]
deps =
    build==1.1.1
commands =
    python -c 'import shutil; shutil.rmtree("{toxinidir}/dist", ignore_errors=True)'
    python -m build -o {toxinidir}/dist

package_glob = {toxinidir}{/}dist{/}wakepy-*-py3-none-any.whl
```

- Pros: Pretty simply to implement
- Cons: This approach has the downside that you will trigger the build (`python -m build`) for each of your environments which do not have `skip_install=True`. This has an open issue: [tox #2729](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/2729).

### Building wheel only once

It is also possible to make tox 4.14.2 build the wheel only once using the tox [hooks](https://tox.wiki/en/4.14.2/plugins.html). As can be seen from the *Order of tox execution* (in Appendix), one hook which can be used for this is the `tox_on_install` for the ".pkg_external" (either "requires" or "deps"). I use it to place a dummy file (`/dist/.TOX-ASKS-REBUILD`) which means that a build should be done. If that `.TOX-ASKS-REBUILD` exists, when the build script is ran, the `/dist` folder with all of its contents is removed, and new `/dist` folder with a .tar.gz and a .whl file is created.

- Pros:

  - Faster to run tox, as sdist and wheel built only as many times as required.
  - Will build also if using tox with single env, like `tox -e py311` (if not `skip_install=True`)
- Cons:

  - More involved
  - Will not work in parallel mode. For that, probably would require to have separate build command which would be ran each time before tox (unless the parallelization plugin supports a common pre-command).

Hopefully this solution will become unnecessary at some point (when #2729 gets resolved)

#### The hook

- Located in a `toxfile.py` at project root.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import typing
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Any

from tox.plugin import impl

if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    from tox.tox_env.api import ToxEnv


dist_dir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "dist"
tox_asks_rebuild = dist_dir / ".TOX-ASKS-REBUILD"


@impl
def tox_on_install(tox_env: ToxEnv, arguments: Any, section: str, of_type: str):
    if (tox_env.name != ".pkg_external") or (of_type != "requires"):
        return

    # This signals to the build script that the package should be built.
    tox_asks_rebuild.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    tox_asks_rebuild.touch()
```

#### The tox_build_mypkg.py

- Located at `/tests/tox_build_mypkg.py`

```py
import shutil
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path

dist_dir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent / "dist"


def build():
    if not (dist_dir / ".TOX-ASKS-REBUILD").exists():
        print("Build already done. skipping.")
        return

    print(f"Building sdist and wheel into {dist_dir}")
    # Cleanup. Remove all older builds; the /dist folder and its contents.
    # Note that tox would crash if there were two files with .whl extension.
    # This also resets the TOX-ASKS-REBUILD so we build only once.
    shutil.rmtree(dist_dir, ignore_errors=True)

    out = subprocess.run(
        f"python -m build -o {dist_dir}", capture_output=True, shell=True
    )
    if out.stderr:
        raise RuntimeError(out.stderr.decode("utf-8"))
    print(out.stdout.decode("utf-8"))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    build()
```

#### The tox.ini

```ini
[testenv]
; The following makes the packaging use the external builder defined in
; [testenv:.pkg_external] instead of using tox to create sdist/wheel.
; https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#external-package-builder
package = external


[testenv:.pkg_external]
; This is a special environment which is used to build the sdist and wheel
; to the dist/ folder automatically *before* any other environments are ran.
; All of this require the "package = external" setting.
deps =
    ; The build package from PyPA. See: https://build.pypa.io/en/stable/
    build==1.1.1
commands =
    python tests/tox_build_mypkg.py

; This determines which files tox may use to install mypkg in the test
; environments. The .whl is created with the tox_build_mypkg.py
package_glob = {toxinidir}{/}dist{/}mypkg-*-py3-none-any.whl
```

### Notes

- This solution requires a fairly new version of tox. The tox_on_install hook [was added in tox 4.0.9](https://tox.wiki/en/4.14.2/changelog.html#v4-0-9-2022-12-13).
- If using any tox extensions and having problems with the hooks being called, try without the tox extension first.
- It is possible to also put the hooks in any *installed* python module and define the location in `pyproject.toml` as described in [Extensions points](https://tox.wiki/en/4.11.4/plugins.html#module-tox.plugin). However, the  `toxfile.py` is a bit handier as it does not have to be *installed* in the current environment.

### Appendix

#### Order of tox execution

The order of execution within tox can be reverse-engineered by using the dummy hook file defined in the Appendix (`tox_print_hooks.py`) and the bullet point list about the order of execution in the [System Overview](https://tox.wiki/en/4.14.2/user_guide.html#system-overview). Note that I have set the `package = external` already which has some effect on the output. Here is what tox does:

```
1) CONFIGURATION
tox_register_tox_env
tox_add_core_config
tox_add_env_config (N+2 times[1])

2) ENVIRONMENT (for each environment)

tox_on_install (envname, deps)
envname: install_deps (if not cached)
    
If not all(skip_install) AND first time: [2]
  tox_on_install (.pkg_external, requires)
  .pkg_external: install_requires (if not cached)
  tox_on_install (.pkg_external, deps)
  .pkg_external: install_deps (if not cached)
      
If not skip_install:
  .pkg_external: commands  
  tox_on_install (envname, package) 
  envname: install_package [3]
    
tox_before_run_commands (envname)
envname: commands
tox_after_run_commands (envname)
  
tox_env_teardown (envname)
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> N = number of environments in tox config file. The "2" comes from .pkg_external and .pkg_external_sdist_meta 
<sup>[2]</sup> "First time" means: First time in this tox call. This is done only if there is at least one selected environment which does not have `skip_install=True`. 
<sup>[3]</sup> This installs the package from wheel. If using the `package = external` in [testenv], it takes the wheel from the place defined by the `package_glob` in the `[testenv:.pkg_external]`

#### The dummy hook file `tox_print_hooks.py`

```py
from typing import Any

from tox.config.sets import ConfigSet, EnvConfigSet
from tox.execute.api import Outcome
from tox.plugin import impl
from tox.session.state import State
from tox.tox_env.api import ToxEnv
from tox.tox_env.register import ToxEnvRegister


@impl
def tox_register_tox_env(register: ToxEnvRegister) -> None:
    print("tox_register_tox_env", register)


@impl
def tox_add_core_config(core_conf: ConfigSet, state: State) -> None:
    print("tox_add_core_config", core_conf, state)


@impl
def tox_add_env_config(env_conf: EnvConfigSet, state: State) -> None:
    print("tox_add_env_config", env_conf, state)


@impl
def tox_on_install(tox_env: ToxEnv, arguments: Any, section: str, of_type: str):
    print("tox_on_install", tox_env, arguments, section, of_type)


@impl
def tox_before_run_commands(tox_env: ToxEnv):
    print("tox_before_run_commands", tox_env)


@impl
def tox_after_run_commands(tox_env: ToxEnv, exit_code: int, outcomes: list[Outcome]):
    print("tox_after_run_commands", tox_env, exit_code, outcomes)


@impl
def tox_env_teardown(tox_env: ToxEnv):
    print("tox_env_teardown", tox_env)
```